# Image doesn't show in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to post an image in the CSS but it's not working

I tried adding the file name but still nothing the file works in HTML but not CSS. I'm not sure if this is file problem or if it's because of the multiple imports

```css
#header {}

#top .logo {}

#top.menu {}

#top .img .background-img {
  background: url('desk-computer.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<section id="top">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>92</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Portfolio</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="background-img">
    <img src=>

    <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you have the CSS and the image in the same file?

Comment: Why is this line suppose to be `<img src=>` ?

Comment: It should be `<img src="desk-computer.jpg">` or `<img src="your_image_name">` instead of `<img src=>`

Comment: You have one class too many here `#top .img .background-img {}` ... there's no element with class `.img` between `#top` and `.background-img`

Comment: As @LGSon pointed out you should change `#top .img .background-img {}` to `#top .background-img {}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put

```
.background-img{
    background-image: url('desk-computer.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

and remove `<img src=>` from html file